# Using regex to find value between square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to find the value inside square brackets. Let's say I have a string like this

```
$str = "This is a test string. I want to get value between [this] and [/this]";
```

So, to explain it pretty clearly, I want to find `[this]` and `[/this]` and then the '`and`' between them. I found some threads here about finding the value inside square brackets but that's not exactly my case, and it did not help. Regex to me is Hebrew to me if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
\[.*?\][^\]]*\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yI3iS2/5)

Your code would be,

```
<?php
$str = "This is a test string. I want to get value between [this] and [/this]";
$regex = '~\[.*?\][^\]]*\]~';
if (preg_match($regex, $str, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=>  [this] and [/this]
```

Comment: umm, you forgot `(` and `)`

Comment: @hjpotter92 don't need for `()` braces. Matching only is enough.

Comment: Thank you Avinash. I managed to get a working solution from this. I used your code and then used 'for' for each value in array and then used explode to split after every " " and the results were Array ( [0] => [this] [1] => and [2] => [/this] )

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\[[^]]*\][^[]*\[[^]]*\]
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rE5cB2/1)

Comment: Why do you guys label the link "*Working* Demo" instead of just "regex online testing example" or something?

Comment: Never thought much about this naming convention but I changed it and will keep in mind in future.

Comment: +1 for effective bracket-fest (I counted 13!) :)

Comment: lol :) @zx81 yes that true its not very readable but it is definitely more efficient than using `.*?`

Comment: Yes, no need to backtrack at every step :)