# Using regex to collect all the elements before squared brackets

Tags: regex, r

I've a column in my dataset with the following structure:

```
x = c("163[330], 164[331], 165[331], 166[330], 167[328] .")
```

The size can vary a bit, from one element to hundreds, my real interest here is to colect all the element numbers before those numbers inside squared brackets. Therefore, my desired output is:

```
y = c(163, 164, 165, 166, 167)
```

I tried this, using a similar [solution for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553265/using-regex-to-find-value-between-square-brackets), but didn't work. How can I use regex to achieve this?

```
> strsplit(x,'~\\[.*?\\][^\\]]*\\]~')[[1]]
[1] "163[330], 164[331], 165[331], 166[330], 167[328] ."
```

Comment: Simpler logic: `as.numeric(sub('\\[.*', '', strsplit(x, ',')[[1]]))` or fewer calls: `as.numeric(strsplit(x, '\\[\\d+\\]\\D+')[[1]])`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
as.numeric(matrix(strsplit(x,split = "\\[|]|,")[[1]],byrow = T,ncol = 3)[,1])
#[1] 163 164 165 166 167
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package which makes it quite straight forward with a look ahead syntax `?=` and pattern `\\d+(?=\\[)` which extracts all digits right before `[` character:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x[1], "\\d+(?=\\[)")[[1]]
# [1] "163" "164" "165" "166" "167"
```

For this specific case with `strsplit`, the `split` could also be `\\[\\d+\\],? \\.?`:

```
strsplit(x[1], "\\[\\d+\\],? \\.?")
# [[1]]
# [1] "163" "164" "165" "166" "167"
```

Comment: Probably the simplest way - `regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+(?=\\[)", x, perl=TRUE) )` in base R.

Comment: The problem when I use this in a data frame I get a column like this: `c("163", "164", "165", "231", "166", "167", "740")`. I mean, inside of a cell, and not just:  `163, 164, 165, 231, 166, 167, 740`.

Comment: How do you use it on your data frame? Can you show a few rows of the data frame?